# Is it possible to use jquery inside a knockout binding declaration?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, knockout.js

Is it possible to use jquery inside a knockout binding declaration? For example, I am trying to select a group of checkboxes by clicking a "All" checkbox. This is how I am trying to declare the click binding:

```
selectAll.bind($parent, $(this).is('checked'))
```

But that seems not to be working. I am getting the following exception in Chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined;
Bindings value: click: $parent.selectAllFacets.bind($parent, $(this).is('checked'))
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFTR, use "jQuery" instead of "$". Specifically, for the example above:

```
function(data, event) {selectAll($parent, jQuery(event.target).is(':checked'))}
```

I was not able to make it work using "bind", but this answer should be more cross browser compatible.

Hope it helps.

Comment: please mark your answer as having answered your question (even though you answered your own question... doing so reduces clutter, plus there's actually a badge for doing that)

Comment: Sure. The only problem is that it doesn't allow me to. I get a "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" message.